# How does Apple's "find -regex" work?

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to create a -regex expression for find on macOS.

```
find /Users/gerben/Library -regex '.*\(cisco\).*' -print 2>/dev/null
```

works, and so does

```
find /Users/gerben/Library -regex '.*\(citrix\).*' -print 2>/dev/null
```

in the sense that they both find files. Now I try

```
find /Users/gerben/Library -regex '.*\(cisco|citrix\).*' -print 2>/dev/null
```

and nothing is found. Nor does

```
find /Users/gerben/Library -regex '.*\(cisco\|citrix\).*' -print 2>/dev/null
```

nor any other variation with {} escapes and what not that I have tried. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `-E` flag, from man:

> `-E`      Interpret regular expressions followed by -regex and -iregex primaries as extended (modern) regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).  The
>                re_format(7) manual page fully describes both formats.

In this case your `find` command will look like:

```
find -E ~/Library -regex '.*(citrix|cisco).*' -print 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Silly me. I was using re_format and has missed the necessity of the -E flag for that. Thanks.

Comment: I just found out that on MacOS, "find" considers a? (meaning 0 or 1 instances of the character a) to be a modern RE feature.  If I want to find files ending in .ts or .tsx, find -regex '.*\.tsx*' works (but finds files ending in .tsxx, etc.) but find -regex '.*\.tsx?' does not work without -E.